# Ordering subfigures in LaTex

Tags: latex, figure, subfigure

I have this code in LaTex:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=50mm]{katua.jpg}}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{txakurren_balioak.png}}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{katuen_balioak.png}}}
\label{fig:eb3}
\end{figure}
```

and I get this:

[image: Image of a cat and two histograms]

And I want to put the images in two columns. In the column of the left the image of the cat and in the right the two histograms. How it is possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `\centering` you could use `\hfill` to do the centering, see the example below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[h!]
     \hfill
     \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-a}} 
     \hfill 
     \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-b}}
     \hfill

     \hfill 
     \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-c}}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]